# Remove nullable property from a custom object type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type that has `null` `void` and `undefined` removed.

```
type TEST = {
  propOne:string
  propTwo: number
  propThree:null  // completely remove this property
}

type CLEAN<T> = { [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]> };

type FIXED = CLEAN<TEST>

const fixed:FIXED={ // error - it wants propThree property
    propOne:'',
    propTwo:1,
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogZRlAvFA3gKClMAnAezAHkA7CALgGdg8BLUgc210LBgHcCKpSBXALYAjCHhb4iMABZ4IlfgBsFOAPQqoAYwICwCiMAgKQUWQIIA3aMCl0qrIqNCYAvpkyhIUAMIAZOAEEAOQAeGAA+VAwoAG0ABSgGKABrCBACADNYAF0eQIJSQL4lAEMhPVC4rIjnAG43D2gAMQBJAA04ABFI3wCQ+CQwty1SGih0ugAPCAATChb2jpQsHBwJEnIKAHJNgBoWVbZObgBGPecgA)

Comment: I cant give you a complete solution, but seems its achieveable with pick - http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Psidom Thank you, your answer got me on the right path. However, I've said a need `null` `void` and `undefined` removed.
So following the documentation link about [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) that you posted I've come up with this solution.

```
type TEST = {
  propOne:string
  propTwo: number
  propThree:void  // completely remove this property
}

type CLEAN<T,K> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends K ? never : P]: T[P] };

const fixed:CLEAN<TEST,void | null | undefined>={
    propOne:'',
    propTwo:1,
}
```

This way I can omit any number of types.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogZRlAvFA3gKClMAnAezAHkA7CALgGdg8BLUgc210LBgHcCKpSBXALYAjCHhb4iMABZ4IlAG4E6AExwB6NVADGBAWAA2EYBH0gosgQXnRgUulVZFRoTAF9MmUJCgBhADJwAIIAcgA8MAB8qBhQANoAClAMUADWECAEAGawUACGDjAJALpQEAAexqTKDvz6+lAAPlB8VRCZDBCqTYoqUAD8vBDWeFA88UU8heNQrgDcHpg6pDRQ7WWdFP5BYfBIEShYODgSJOQUAOTnADQsx2yc3ACMN65AA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) with conditional types to map nullable keys to `never` which will remove the property from the result type:

```
type CLEAN<T> = { [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? never : P]: T[P] };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=75&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogZRlAvFA3gKClMAnAezAHkA7CALgGdg8BLUgc210LBgHcCKpSBXALYAjCHhb4iMABZ4IlfgBsFOAPQqoAYwICwCiMAgKQUWQIIA3aMCl0qrIqNCYAvpkyhIUAMIAZOAEEAOQAeGAA+VAwoAG0ABSgGKABrCBACADNYKABDO0VlCAAPA1IAEzsYOIBdKAB+XghLPCgeWKqeSraoZwBuNw9oADEASQANOAARSN8AkPgkMLctUhoodLpCiFKKEfGJlCwcHAkScgoAcnOAGhZjtk5uAEYb5yA)